# Misunderstanding of ML.WEIGHTS in BigQuery ML?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have trained a [linear.reg](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-create) model in BigQuery on a very simple dataset:

Two columns **t** and **x** with **x** ranging from 1 to 49 and **t** being by construction **0.3 * x**

So I expected the learned model to be something close to **t = 0.3 * x + ~0**.
[image]

As you can see above the prediction for x = 100 looks fine but I do not understand the weights given by ML.WEIGHTS:

- 4.29 for x
- 7.51 for the intercept

I know BigQuery ML is still on beta but does anyone have an explanation?

Answer (score 5):

Ok I found the explanation: the training data are standardized before learning.

Comment: Could you explain a bit better, what this means, what does a 'standardization' do to the training data.

Comment: @Pentium10  standardization is one sort of data normalization or feature scaling
how? for a given feature, substract its mean value and divide by its standard deviation, at the end you got features with zero mean and unit variance
why? consider the Euclidean distance used in many ML algorithms, with no normalization one single feature with a broad range of values would dominate